# opening an external interface project using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, interface

I've been working an java application and designing an interface on eclipse in my friend's laptop, then, i needed to move everything to my laptop and continue working there. 
But, when i moved the entire folder of my project which is called "RPSgame" to my laptop, and un-zipped it and put it in my workspace, i didn't know how to open the interface and continue working on it as nothing happened.
I tried using File > Open then opened the jar files, but it didn't work 
the RPSgame is the folder i'm trying to open the interface from

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
Right clic in explorer view > Import...> General - Existing projects into workspace > Select root directory (then select your project) and finish
```

If your project is already into workspace, don't tick `copy projects into workspace`